# Should I separate the "files" table to "audios", "images" and "documents" or should all be in one place?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a File model and of course files table for uploaded files. They are separated by a "type" column and are used in different places like gallery and player.

```
id | name     | type    | mime ...
--------------------------------------
0  | nature   | image   | image/jpeg
1  | desert   | image   | image/jpeg
2  | jazz     | audio   | audio/mp3
3  | pop      | audio   | audio/mp3
```

I was thinking if it would be better to create separated models, controllers and tables, or should I use it all in one. I can't decide which system would be more efficient.

Comment: I would be better o have separate table for both the file types. And accordingly controller and model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to used them separated and so I did. But after a while I needed videos and documents too. I had to create for each type new model, controller and views, which was not quite convenient. So my decision changed. I guess it would be better to use only file model for all media types.

Comment: I think it would be convenient to create a "File Type" model, Controller etc. and save the types to a database table and get/set the type by a type ID for the files. You could have all the type linked functions there but the structure would be clear. And if needed you could then add a control page to your admin side to add, update and remove types. The separate table for file types would also allow you to add extra options like mime there.

Comment: @mMoovs That is for sure what I will do next time.